# How to convert string to mongoDB.Bson.ObjectId

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am working in Asp.net C# and database is MongoDb,
I want to convert the userID (entered by console) to ObjectId.

ObjectId userId = System.Console.ReadLine();

How it can be done ?

Comment: Okay. So what is the output type from your ReadLine method? A String right? And what can you pass as a constructor to a "new" ObjectId? There should be enough hint in there for you to solve this yourself. Restating "new".

Comment: ObjectId userId = new ObjectId (System.Console.ReadLine());
Like this ? Neil ?

Comment: Better as two lines of code probably. But you are getting the idea